# Yii User management, display user profile info

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Hi I am using yii with the yii-user-management extension

I can see how it's fairly simple to get some of the current logged user info which is stored in the users table (e.g. Yii::app()->user->name)

However I was wondering how would it be possible to get related data of the current logged user (e.g. user email which is stored in the profiles tables)

in the YumUser.php model file there is a relation

```
$relations['profile'] = array(self::HAS_ONE, 'YumProfile', 'user_id');
```

However I am not sure how to use this directly in a View file

Comment: thanks but that topic is completely unrelated to my question

Comment: Are you using the UserIdentity component?

Comment: no I am not, I am using yii-user-management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a cleaner way to do this is suggested by the YUM docs. There is a data() method in YumWebUser that makes the user model accessible from the WebUser instance:

```
// Use this function to access the AR Model of the actually
// logged in user, for example
public function data() {
    if($this->_data instanceof YumUser)
        return $this->_data;
    else if($this->id && $this->_data = YumUser::model()->findByPk($this->id))
        return $this->_data;
    else
        return $this->_data = new YumUser();
}
```

So, you should be able to simply use:

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->user->data()->profile->firstname; ?>
<?php echo Yii::app()->user->data()->profile->email; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will need info that won't vary in the time the user is logged in, you should use `setState()` function at LOGIN time.

Example:

```
class MySqlUserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{

  private $_id;

  public function authenticate()
  {
    $user = User::model()->findByAttributes( array( 'username' => $this->username ) );
    if( $user === null )
      $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else if( $user->password !== md5( $this->password ) )
      $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
      $this->_id = $user->id;
      $this->setState( 'username', $user->username );
      $this->setState( 'name', $user->name );
      $this->setState( 'surname', $user->surname );
      $this->setState( 'email', $user->email );
      $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
  }

  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->_id;
  }
}
```

That way this info is saved in session and you won't need to access the DB every time.

Example:

```
echo Yii::app()->user->email;
```

Answer (score 0):

ok found out myself

In the action of the controller file I should put

```
$user_profile = YumUser::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id)->profile;
$this->render('index', array('user_profile' => $user_profile));
```

Then from the view

```
<?php echo $user_profile->firstname ?>
<?php echo $user_profile->email ?>
```

and so on...